# Datepicker is shown behind modal window

Tags: ajax, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

Datepicker shown behind modal window

The datepicker input is shown in the background of the modal window no matter what I try.
This is loaded through ajax which updates a partial view with relevant info.

Tried setting z-index:

```
 #ui-datepicker-div {
    z-index: 9999 !important;
}
```

Also tried loading datepicker after modal window is shown:

```
  $('#modalPlaceHolder').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
            $('[data-toggle="datepicker"]').datepicker();
        });
```

Ajax:

```
 $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'get',
            cache: false,
            data: 'memberId=' + memberId,
            success: function (data) {
                $('#modalPlaceHolder').html(data);
                $('#modalPlaceHolder > .modal').modal('show');
                $('#preloader').delay(350).fadeOut('slow');
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                bootbox.alert({
                    message: xhr.status + " || " + thrownError,
                    callback: function () {
                        $('#preloader').delay(350).fadeOut('slow');
                    }
                });
                window.location.reload();
            }
        });

        $('#modalPlaceHolder').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
            $('[data-toggle="datepicker"]').datepicker();
        });
```

The partialview:

```
 <div class="modal fade" id="edit-member" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="editMemberLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="editMemberLabel">@Resources.Global.EditUser</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
            </button>
        </div>
 <div class="form-group">
                        <label asp-for="KeyExpiryDateFormatted">@Resources.Global.EndDate</label>
                        <input data-toggle="datepicker" asp-for="KeyExpiryDateFormatted" id="ui-datepicker-div" class="form-control" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="KeyExpiryDateFormatted" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you applied a `position` to the `#ui-datepicker-div`?

Comment: hmmm. no I haven't. can you give me an example?

Comment: I believe `z-index` only works if you specify either `position: absolute` or `position: relative` to the element you're applying it to.

Comment: did not work :(

Comment: Are you able to share a link or more code?

Comment: it's a lot of code... what part do you need? I think i have the relevant parts here..

Comment: Well, for example, you're only showing the CSS for one element.

Comment: no more css than that added.. uses the bootstrap css.